# MemoryError when extracting articles into list using gensim WikiCorpus

Tags: nlp, gensim

I wish to build a corpus from a Wikipedia Dump (~19GB compressed .bz2 file). But, I encountered MemoryError when I try to run the code as shown. Is there any solution that can solve this issue?

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning, module='gensim')
from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus
import sys


def make_corpus(in_f, out_f):
    output = open(out_f, 'w')
    print("File Created!")
    wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f)
    print("Wiki Opened!")
    i = 0

    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        output.write(bytes(' '.join(text).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8') + '\n')
        i = i + 1
        if (i % 10000 == 0):
            print('Processed ' + str(i) + ' articles...')

    output.close()
    print('Processing Completed!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) !=3:
        sys.exit(1)

    in_f = sys.argv[1]
    out_f = sys.argv[2]
    make_corpus(in_f, out_f)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
> exitcode = _main(fd)
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
> prepare(preparation_data)
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
> *fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in *fixup_main_from_path
> run_name="**mp_main**")
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
> pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in *run_module_code
> mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
> File "d:\LeongJC\FYP_Code\Code\wikipedia_transformation.py", line 3, in 
> import gensim
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim_*init**.py", line 11, in 
> from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, utils  # noqa:F401
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora_*init**.py", line 6, in 
> from .indexedcorpus import IndexedCorpus  # noqa:F401 must appear before the other classes
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\indexedcorpus.py", line 14, in 
> from gensim import interfaces, utils
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\interfaces.py", line 19, in 
> from gensim import utils, matutils
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py", line 19, in 
> from scipy.stats import entropy
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_*init**.py", line 388, in 
> from .stats import *
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 174, in 
> from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial_*init**.py", line 101, in 
> from .*procrustes import procrustes
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial_procrustes.py", line 9, in 
> from scipy.linalg import orthogonal_procrustes
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg_*init**.py", line 194, in 
> from .misc import *
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 4, in 
> from .lapack import get_lapack_funcs
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\lapack.py", line 783, in 
> from scipy.linalg import _flapack
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
> multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
> """
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
> result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\wikicorpus.py", line 530, in _process_article
> token_max_len=token_max_len, lower=lower,
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\wikicorpus.py", line 490, in process_article
> result = tokenizer_func(text, token_min_len, token_max_len, lower)
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\wikicorpus.py", line 361, in tokenize
> utils.to_unicode(token) for token in utils.tokenize(content, lower=lower, errors='ignore')
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 264, in tokenize
> text = text.lower()
> MemoryError
> """

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "d:/LeongJC/FYP_Code/Code/wikipedia_transformation.py", line 31, in 
> make_corpus(in_f, out_f)
> File "d:/LeongJC/FYP_Code/Code/wikipedia_transformation.py", line 11, in make_corpus
> wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f)
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\wikicorpus.py", line 639, in **init**
> self.dictionary = Dictionary(self.get_texts())
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\dictionary.py", line 78, in **init**
> self.add_documents(documents, prune_at=prune_at)
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\dictionary.py", line 196, in add_documents
> for docno, document in enumerate(documents):
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\wikicorpus.py", line 693, in get_texts
> for tokens, title, pageid in pool.imap(_process_article, group):
> File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 735, in next
> raise value
> MemoryError

[CMD Error Message1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ0xA.png)
[CMD Error Message2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHfjo.png)

Comment: You could try to process the data one doc at a time instead of loading the full data in memory, see [gensim doc](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_corpora_and_vector_spaces.html#corpus-streaming-one-document-at-a-time). Btw it would be better to copy/paste the error message in the question as text.

Comment: How many docs are you getting through until the exception is raised? i.e. do you get something printed to the screen from command `print('Processed ' + str(i) + ' articles...')`?

Comment: @KyleFHartzenberg I don't get through any of the docs. The exception was raised on the `wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `WikiCorpus` class surveys the entire dump file's vocabulary upon creation, even though most users don't need that. And, it's during that step you're hitting this `MemoryError`.

However, if you supply an empty Python `dict` at `WikiCorpus` creation, it'll skip this time-consuming & memory-consuming step. A

Specifically, change your line...

```py
    wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f)
```

...to...

```py
    wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f, dictionary={})
```

After this change, you may not have any further problems, as it looks like your code is otherwise doing things in an incremental fashion that shouldn't use much memory even on a small-memory machine.

Comment: It seems to work now but there's another exception raised (_Error: [WinError 1455] The paging file is too small for this operation to complete_, I currently have customed total allocated 10GB of paging file size for all drives)

Comment: Few hours ago, I was able to run for a while until a period, the program frozed. And I tried to re-run again and keep getting back the MemoryError now.

Comment: @LeongJC How much physical RAM do you have in your system?

Comment: @KyleFHartzenberg I have 16GB of physical RAM.

Comment: If supplying the empty `dict` solved the 1st problem, what you ahve now is a new problem. It's hard to analyze an error stack in these comments; you should either (1) edit your question with all the updated details of the current shape of the problem, including the exact code you're running & full error message(s) and other output you're getting (including any progress shown before the error; or (2) post a new question with all the required info. It may not be very related.

Comment: @gojomo Noted. But currently, the code somehow works and has completed execution; I am not sure why.

Comment: Glad to hear it! One of the reasons that, after surmounting one problem, it's good to treat any subsequent problem separately – perhaps even with a standalone question – is that the mere act of reformulation can sometimes eliminate what's going wrong, which might be some transient result of half-applied fixes, or fragmentary previous fix-attempts. Maybe that happened here: while you were getting new errors, there was still code cruft or bad-state from prior tinkering.